# Why does Google Translate have trouble with Latin?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

I would have guessed that Latin, being a [synthetic language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_language), would be much easier for a computer to translate, than an analytic language like English.  But is this true?

What is it that causes Google Translate difficulties with a simple sentence like the one below.  What gives it reason to omit "mother"?

[image]

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site! A number of users think the linked question has an answer to yours. You might want to take the time to read it and decide whether your doubt has been satisfactorily answered there, or you want to reword this question to ask something more specific.

Comment: At times, the philosophy of quickly closing questions _deemed_ duplicate by the community might prove frustrating to some of us. I know the feel. But that's the way it works, and also has collateral benefits